# Write PM2 logs to custom path

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

I use PM2 to execute my Node.js app.
In order to do that, I have defined the following `ecosystem` config file:

```yaml
apps:
  - script: app.js
    name: "myApp"
    exec_mode: cluster
    cwd: "/etc/myService/myApp"
```

Everything is working. Now I want to specify the custom location for the PM2's logs, therefore I added into `ecosystem` config file:

```yaml
log: "/etc/myService/myApp/logs/myApp.log"
```

It works, but I paid attention that after execution of `pm2 start ecosystem`, PM2 will write the logs to **both** locations at the same time:

- `/etc/myService/myApp/logs/myApp.log` (as expected)
- `/home/%$user%/.pm2/logs/` (default logs destination)

How can I specify the only place for logs of PM2 and avoid the duplicate logs generation?

Comment: I suggest you make the directory .pm2 root/read only so that pm2 cannot write to it.

Comment: Look at `out_file`: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#log-files

Comment: @robertklep , worked! Please, arrange your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: @MikeB. thb I don't know what the exact syntax of the config file would look like, feel free to answer your question yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment of **[robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep)**, in order to solve the issue we have to use `out_file` and `err_file` fields for output and error log paths respectively.

Syntax sample in YAML format:

```
out_file: "/etc/myService/myApp/logs/myApp_L.log"
err_file: "/etc/myService/myApp/logs/myApp_E.log"
```

P.S. The field `log` can be removed from the config file:

```
log: "/etc/myService/myApp/logs/myApp.log"
```